How to build local emacs-29 without sudo
I'm on a Linux system, without any admin privileges. There is no /etc/release file so I don't know the distro, but FWIW there's a yum command if that helps narrow it down.
uname -rmo = 4.18.0-513.24.1.lve.el8.x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Following these instructions, I dl'ed emacs-29.4, ran configure:
./configure --prefix=/home/tdnhffeh/private --bindir=/home/tdnhffeh/private/bin --without-x --with-gnutls=ifavailable

It ran fine. Then ran make && make install:
configure: error: You do not seem to have makeinfo >= 4.13, and your
source tree does not seem to have pre-built manuals in the 'info' directory.
Please install a suitable version of makeinfo.

I don't know what makeinfo is and I don't really care about doc, I just need to be able to run command-line emacs. Is there a way to finish this installation?

Use emacs-29.1 instead. It doesn't require makeinfo.
(I don't know if this is an error in the emacs-29.4 distribution, or whether 29.2 or 29.3 will also work, but 29.1 configures and builds fine for me.)

I'm guessing you found a bug, good job!
